# How can I display the selected data from a ComboBox from one window to another with WPF and MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm at the beginning of the road in learning the two concepts of WPF and MVVM. I am currently working on an application called: quiz app. Basically, I would like the user to write their name in the first window and select the difficulty level of the questions in the quiz.

The first window looks like that:

[image]

What I want to do next is that when the user writes his name and selects the difficulty level, the Next button will open another window in which to display the following message:

Welcome, 'his name'!
You selected the 'easy / medium / difficult' level for the quiz!

I searched a lot of tutorials but I didn't find anything. Most of them displayed the two messages in the same window but I would like to display them in a new window.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seeing as how they just entered their name and chose the difficulty level, it seems a little odd that the next step is just to show them that data again. I would have thought once you enter name and choose difficulty level the next step might be questions. Which you'll have to put somewhere. A viewmodel that has name, level, score and a list of questions, answers, option chosen and bool for correct of not seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open new window, you must create instance of its class (so you have to call constructor).

On the other hand, you have all data in welcome screen, so I would suggest following:

1. Define constructor of your "next window" that accepts required arguments:

```
// Constructor of next window
public NextWindow(string name, string level)
{
    // If you are using MVVM, you want DataContext to hold data, so
    // you most probably create your Datacontext here
    var vm = new NextWindowViewModel();
    // So you need to define appropriate properties in you ViewModel
    vm.Name = name;
    vm.Level = level;
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

2. Now you can bind to properties of your view model and use them :)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this:

- Create `Main View Model`, it will have a property called `Current View Model`, which is of type either base view model or observable object or whatever you kids call it these days.
- Create a main window which will have a Content Control, it's content would be bound to Current View Model.
- Create a `User Control` for Login (your current view).
- Create `Login View Model`.
- Set `Login VM` as default when you create `Main View Model`.
- Now create `Next Window VM` which will hold that name and difficulty setting.
- Create User Control for that vm as well.
- create data templates in main window for each type of VMs, so the Content Control knows what to use.
- Now that you have both VMs ready for you then you would implement a messenger pattern. Like in this example [Git hub link](https://gist.github.com/sachintha81/7b56aa5704409e055b8bbd33a27c9482).
  Now when you need to pass information from LoginVM to NextWindowVM you retrieve it from instance of LoginVM or message, through messenger. This way you can navigate through as many VMs as you want and reuse the same window.
  Now I know you are just starting with WPF and MvvM so I am guessing you'll need pointers on how to do this in xaml:
  Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WPF_UserControls;assembly=WPF_UserControls" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">  
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
            <views:Login/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NextWindowViewModel}">
            <views:NextWindow/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Close" Command="{Bidning CloseCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As I look at your question I see that field warining about "MainWindow.SelectedDegree", not only it's a field (won't work with WPF Binding, needs to be a property), it's not really how MvvM works. Let us know if you need any more help.